# How to limit the length of a regex

Tags: regex, cmd, findstr

I want to use this regex with `FINDSTR`, but it's too long, as `FINDSTR`'s search string has to be less than 128 characters.

```
\b((((Mr)|(Mrs)|(Ms)|(Fr)|(St)|(Sr)|(Rev)|(Dr))\.)\s?)?(((([A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z]\.?))(\s(([A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z]\.?)))?)|(([A-Z]\.?){1,2}))?\s((([A-Z][a-z]+)\-([A-Z][a-z]+))|(([A-Z][a-z]+)\'([A-Z][a-z]+))|([A-Z][a-z]+))\b
```

What should I do?

Comment: "Plz send teh codez" is not appropriate.

Comment: I believe the title should be "How to limit the length a given regular expression will match?" based on "everything matched [..] that is [*also*] less than X characters". However, this *disagrees* with the diagram presented (otherwise I would have made the title change myself). Questions with such ambiguity/contradiction are prone to being down-voted and closed ..

Comment: @abelenky Sorry about that, I tried to fix it based on user2864740's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Fr|St|Sr|Rev|Dr)((\s[A-Z]\.?|[\s\-][A-Z]\w+))*([\s\-][A-Z]\w+)+
```

That matches:

- Mr John Smith-Edwards
- Dr A R. Smith
- Mr John P. Smith